# ListBoxItem Style preserve MouseOver and Selected Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, storyboard, multitrigger

I have a ListBox where I want to display the current State with a colored `Rectangle` sliding out.

When The Item is `Selected` **or** `MouseOver` the `Recangle` should extend otherwise it should shrink.

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MoveOutStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation To="175"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatingGrid">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                To="White" />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MoveInStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation To="16"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatingGrid">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                To="Black" />
    </Storyboard>
</ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

As there is no 'or' Multitrigger I figured out the following Trigger:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>

    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But Somehow the `MoveOutStoryboard` is never called when I have the last `MultiTrigger` set, but I cannot figure out why.

Thanks for yor help.

Comment: Those two storyboards animate the same properties? Try to stop active storyboard before activating new one to give access to animated properties.

Comment: share some sample code for `MoveOutStoryboard` & `MoveInStoryboard`

Comment: I added the Storyboards to my question. In my understanding the MoveInStorybard activated by the last trigger should override the previous animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since another animation can not take control over a property unless started by the same trigger, so give this a try

```
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                     Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
```

if you face the issue with mouse over and IsSelected then use this

```
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveIn2" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveOut2" />
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveOut1"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveIn2" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveOut2" />
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveIn1"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                     Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveIn1" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveOut1" />
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveOut2"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveIn1" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveOut1" />
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveIn2"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
```

also remove the multitrigger, that may not be necessary, or you can combine the remove storyboard approach in with your approach, that should work too.

---

**EDIT**

here is your approach with the RemoveStoryboard, this is working, I tested too

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="multi" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sel" />
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="over"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="multi" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="over" />
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="sel"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>

        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sel" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="over" />
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="multi"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

or this, but this may be buggy and you can see some snaps in animation

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="over"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="over" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="sel"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sel" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="multi"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="multi" />
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: First approach is working until you select and deselect an item. Then it won't show the MouseOver effect anymore. Second approach won't stay in selected state :(

Comment: did you also tried to combine the remove storyboard with your approach using multitrigger?

Answer (score 1):

So after many many tries and with the help of pushpraj I got the final solution. Maybe it will help anybody having the same problem:

```
<MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveIn1" />
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveOut2" />
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveOut1"
                                         Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveOut2"
                                         Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveOutStoryboard}" />
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="False" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="moveOut2" />
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="moveIn1"
                                         Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveInStoryboard}" />
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
```

Comment: great find! these things gets really tricky when you have to manipulate same property in different animations/triggers.